# Mysql JOIN с подзапросом и производительность

Tags: mysql, база-данных, inner-join

хотелось бы узнать немного теории про join с подзапросом.
допустим у нас имеется запрос

```
select from a inner join (select * from b) as bb on a.id = bb.id
```

таблица b может иметь миллионы записей. насколько ограничить по определенным критериям запрос bb так как данные неизвестны пока не прошла выборка главного запроса.

насколько медленным может быть запрос при условии что мы поставим условие where bb.tag=1
по сравнению с просто присоединением таблицы и тем же where ? пример:

```
select from a inner join b on a.id = b.id where b.tag=1
```

просто интересно знать как будет работать  join . мне кажется join sub будет работать медленно. так как для начала ему придется сделать выборку. а там миллионы строк . затем соединить по условию.

может я не прав. хотелось бы увидеть документацию по алгоритмам работы, но не нашел.

Comment: SQL - декларативный язык. Ты серверу задание, он тебе результат. Как он его получит - это его дело, и не факт что оно будет похоже на текст запроса. В данном случае почти наверняка для обоих запросов будет построен один и тот же план выполнения.

Comment: Просто хотелось бы узнать может у кого была практика с такими запросами. как они себя ведут на раздутых базах. самому проверить не представляется пока возможным

Comment: Ну вот убей не понимаю вопроса... как сервер выполняет запрос, если он написан через задницу...

Comment: прям вот такой запрос в целом оторван от действительности. На больших таблицах писать джойн/where не опираясь на какой-либо индекс будет выстрелом не в ногу даже, а куда-то явно повыше. Используйте `EXPLAIN`  для запросов и оценки того, как он будет выполнятся. Увидите, что порядок выборки из таблиц может быть совсем не тот, что указан в запросе, и собственно не всегда это будет хорошо. В указанно примере `where b.tag = ..` будет применено к таблице до джйона, а не после